# Tomcat 7.0.76 HTTP Status 500

Tags: java, tomcat, firewall

Boa noite pessoal,

Estou quebrando a cabeça com esse CentOS 7.0.
A história é o seguinte:

Montei uma máquina com CentOS 7.0 e instalei o Tomcat. Até aí maravilha, acessei a página padrão que ele confirma a instalação.

Minha equipe de desenvolvimento começou a migrar meu sistema que está em outro ambiente para o novo que montei.

Porém está dando esse erro na página

[image: Apache TOMCAT HTTP500 STATUS]

Nos logs do Catalina aparece isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que será que pode ser??? 
Utilizo os seguintes softwares e versões:

Tomcat 7.0.76
Java 1.7.0_80
FirewallD

Obrigado desde já a quem puder me ajudar!!!

Comment: Parece ser problema com o Firewall, que está bloqueando algo que antes ele não bloqueava. Pode ser também algum problema de configuração devido a IPs e nomes de hosts terem mudado.

Comment: Ah, e se atente a isso: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/132

Comment: Por sinal, sem ver os seus arquivos de configuração, fica muito difícil de se responder a sua pergunta, pois qualquer tipo de resposta seria baseada em tentativa de se adivinhar o seu problema na base do chute. Assim sendo, é uma boa ideia editar a pergunta e acrecsentar essas informações.